# Path integral on many-body quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, path-integral, many-body, grassmann-numbers

Suppose $\mathscr{H}$ is a Hilbert space describing a one-particle quantum system and $\mathcal{F}(\mathscr{H})$ is its associated Fock space, which is used to describe a many-body quantum system. Let us focus on many-fermions system, so we are actually considering the fermionic Fock space $\mathcal{F}_{\text{fer}}(\mathscr{H})$.

If $\mathscr{H}$ has dimension $n < +\infty$, then $\mathcal{F}_{\text{fer}}(\mathscr{H})$ has dimension $2^{n}$. If $\beta > 0$ and $A$ is any linear operator on $\mathcal{F}_{\text{fer}}(\mathscr{H})$, we can use the Lie-Trotter formula to write:
$$\operatorname{Tr}e^{-\beta A} = \lim_{N \to \infty}\operatorname{Tr}(1-\frac{\beta}{N}A)^{N}) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Formula (\ref{1}) is the usual way of giving mathematical meaning to path integrals.

Consider the following object:
$$\int d\mu_{C}(\bar{\psi},\psi)e^{-\lambda V(\bar{\psi},\psi)} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
which is a Grassmann Gaussian integral with propagator (covariance) $C$, coupling constant $\lambda$ and interaction potential $V$. In the mathematical physics literature, it is commonly said that to study fermionic systems it is sufficient to study (\ref{2}) where *the number of Grassmann variables $\bar{\psi}$ and $\psi$ is finite*. Usually, the justification for this statement is that the trace inside the limit in the right hand side of (\ref{1}) can be written as an integral of the form (\ref{2}) when $A$ is taken to be the Hamiltonian $H$ of the system. In this case, the propagator $C$ comes from the quadratic part of the Hamiltonian and $V$ comes from its interaction term.

The point that I do not understand is how (\ref{2}) with finitely many Grassmann variables is enough to study many-body fermionic systems. Even when the trace in the right hand side of (\ref{1}) is written in terms of an integral of the form (\ref{2}), there is a limit (which, at least formally, would lead to an infinitely-many generated Grassmann algebra) $N \to \infty$ to be considered and, *more importantly*, even if this limit is evaluated, we would have only a theory on a discrete finite lattice, which is far from what one wants!

What am I missing here?

**Note:** I know Grassmann algebras with countable many generators can be rigorously defined and studied, but the point is that it is always explicitly stated that one does not need it to study fermionic theories. Hence, I am not interested in answers such as "you could use infinitely many generators" etc.

Comment: Commonly said where? Which page?

Comment: Unless you are studying ghost fermions, its Hamiltonian is not quadratic. Ordinary fermion Lagrangian density is a first-order system, where only first order time-derivative of the Grassmann-number-valued field appears.